# Requests and internet access is blocked in my Vue.js - Cordova App on IOS13

Tags: cordova, vue.js, ios13

Currently I am trying to release a new version of my app but I am facing big problems with IOS13.
The app is built and runs on IOS13 devices but I cannot connect to a server or even load an image from the web. Same app works perfectly fine on IOS12.

Because my app used the UIWebView and it is deprecated I thought this is the cause why the network access is blocked so I tried to get it running with WKWebView but still there is the same problem.

**Here is the output message of my build:**

[image: X-Code build-output]
**FYI:** *ERROR: Internal navigation rejected* was already solved and also had no effect

Answer (score 0):

Error was caused by the AbortController that i use in my requests. The problem was the initialization which worked on ios12 but not on ios13.